# Why are first two buttons jumping when i push third?

Tags: html, css

```js
function clickListener() {
   loader.style.display = 'inline-block';
   title.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
button {
    height: 3rem;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#loader {
    display: none;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button onclick="clickListener()">
     <span id="title">Push</span>
     <span id="loader"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Browser: chrome

Comment: The weird behavior with the buttons shifting around is because they are `inline`/`inline-block` and therefore aligned by baseline, and the one has no text content, which means they have different baselines.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes Thanks man! I set line-height: 12px; for third button and all works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click the button, the listener `clickListener()` is called. Once it's called, clickListener changes the CSS properties of the button's children (".title" and ".loader").

*This has nothing to do with JavaScript. This is a CSS problem.*

When you change the display type of ".loader", CSS is shifting the position to the right because the button overflows out of it's parent container, when `inline` is similar to `block`.

You can achieve the same effect for the button via using `inline-block` instead, or just setting the `textContent` to "" (nothing).

You also had a typo in your code, you ended `<span>` with a `</div>` instead.

**Update:** after you updated your answer, you also implied you added extra CSS to the button and it had the same effect. It looks like you tried to use `margin` inside the button. Margin is like outer-padding, it outputs extra whitespace outside of the element. You need to either use `padding` instead, or position the element specifically using something like `margin-left`, etc.

Here is an example of using `inline-block` instead of `inline`:

```js
function clickListener() {
   loader.style.display = 'inline-block';
   title.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
button {
    height: 3rem;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#loader {
    display: none;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button onclick="clickListener()">
     <span id="title">Push</span>
     <span id="loader"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: NIce try! I add 'inline-block' to the question, it helps, but in original code i have more css, so i add it too and buttons still jumping even with inline-block(

Comment: @Darth sorry to hear that, did you change the closing </div> tag problem?

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your HTML code is the problem here. You have a mismatched closing div tag for the third button, and the Push should be inside the third button element.

The loader and title elements should be defined somewhere in your HTML, possibly as references to existing elements using JavaScript. Its missing in your code.

Here is your updated code:

```js
const loader = document.getElementById('loader');
    const title = document.getElementById('title');

    function clickListener() {
      loader.style.display = 'inline';
      title.style.display = 'none';
    }
```

```css
button {
      height: 3rem;
      padding: 0 1rem;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }

    #loader {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="buttons">
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button onclick="clickListener()">
      <span id="title">Push</span>
      <span id="loader"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, i lost this while making a snippet. It was div in original code

Answer (score 0):

Here's what happens in Firefox.
[image]

It's because you are hiding the text and showing an empty element.  The other reason is because you have `<span id="title">Push</div>` - it begins with `<span` and closes with `</div>` so the browser is trying to correct this for you and it's not working correctly.

Also, you have never defined the variables `title` and `loader` - honestly I'm amazed this code does anything at all, I've never seen this done this way.

Here's a much better and cleaner way of doing this. The click listener should be added in JS. If you do this and use classes instead of ID's then you can make this work easily for as many buttons as you need it to.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.load-on-click')].forEach(function(loadBtn) {
  loadBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    const btnTitle = loadBtn.querySelector('.btn-title');
    const btnLoader = loadBtn.querySelector('.btn-loader');

    btnLoader.style.display = 'inline';
    btnTitle.style.display = 'none';
  });
});
```

```css
button {
    height: 3rem;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.btn-loader {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button class="load-on-click">
     <span class="btn-title">Push 3</span>
     <span class="btn-loader">loading 3...</span>
  </button>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="buttons">
  <button>4</button>
  <button>5</button>
  <button class="load-on-click">
     <span class="btn-title">Push 6</span>
     <span class="btn-loader">loading 6...</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: In chrome you dont need to define variables for elements with id, it already defined by browser for you, so i avoid this step for keeping snippet short

Comment: @Darth Short and helluva confusing.

Comment: @Darth That's a neat trick, but honestly I would avoid doing that. That's not a good practice to just hope the browser defines your variables for you.

Comment: I never do it in production)

Comment: Ha, well that counts for something at least ! :)